# Beautifulsoup removing duplicated parent and child tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to remove duplicated tags which surround text from the output of BeautifulSoup.

The `scrape_selected_tags` is a BeautifulSoup type of `bs4.element.ResultSet` which outputs:

```
[<img/>]
[<img/> <a>1</a> <a>1</a> <a><b>1</b></a> <a><b>1</b><c>3</c></a> <img/>]
```

I try and remove duplicates like so:

```
check_list = []

for i in scrape_selected_tags:
    if i not in check_list:
        check_list.append(i)
    else:
        "".join(re.findall("<\w+>|</\w+>|<\w+/>", str(i)))

print check_list
```

This outputs:

```
[<img/>]
[<img/>, <a>1</a>, <a><b>1</b></a>, <a><b>1</b><c>3</c></a>]
```

removing the duplicated `<a>1</a>` and `<img>` from the second element in `scrape_selected_tags`. However, I'd like to keep the  `<img>` tag as it doesn't surround text, and I'd like to keep the tags `<a></a>` to demonstrate `<a>1</a>` was originally there, i.e. outputting:

```
[<img/>]
[<img/>, <a>1</a>, <a></a>, <a><b>1</b></a>, <a><b>1</b><c>3</c></a>, <img/>]
```

How can I modify my code to do this?

I also want to apply this with duplicated child tags. My final desired output would be the following, where `<b>1</b>` is removed from the last element, but the `<b></b>` tags remain.

```
[<img/>]
[<img/>, <a>1</a>, <a></a>, <a><b>1</b></a>, <a><b></b><c>3</c></a>, <img/>]
```

I have tried to loop over the `check_list` using a new for loop:

```
for i in [child for parent in check_list for child in parent.find_all()]:
    print i
```

This retrieves all the child tags. Removing them using the same method as the parent tags does not work. I can't use the `set` function as I want to keep tags that do not contain string, such as `<img>`. This is why I have used regular expressions.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the first part of your question,  you can use list of tag names to keep and chack if the `Tag.name` string is included in the list.
For the duplicate tags, you could create new `Tag` objects with no text content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

scrape_selected_tags = ['<img/>', '<a>1</a>', '<a>1</a>', '<a><b>1</b></a>', '<a><b>1</b><c>3</c></a>', '<img/>']
scrape_selected_tags = [BeautifulSoup(tag, 'html.parser').find() for tag in scrape_selected_tags]

keep = ['img']
check_list = []

for i in scrape_selected_tags:
    if i not in check_list or i.name in keep:
        check_list.append(i)
    else:
        check_list.append(Tag(name=i.name))

print check_list
```

> `[<img/>, <a>1</a>, <a></a>, <a><b>1</b></a>, <a><b>1</b><c>3</c></a>, <img/>]`

---

Applying those rules to nested tags is a bit harder. You'll have to flatten the items in `check_list` in order to check if any tag nested in the new item is included in any tags already in the list.

If it is, create a new empty `Tag` and use the [`replace_with`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) method to replace the old tag, before adding the item to the list.

```
for i in scrape_selected_tags:
    tag = i if i not in check_list or i.name in keep else Tag(name=i.name)
    for child in tag.find_all():
        if child in [ct for pt in check_list for ct in [pt] + pt.find_all()]:
            child.replace_with(Tag(name=child.name))
    check_list.append(tag)

print check_list
```

> `[<img/>, <a>1</a>, <a></a>, <a><b>1</b></a>, <a><b></b><c>3</c></a>, <img/>]`